# How can I convert a number into a lower number with the same relative position?

Tags: logic

I have got a world with the size of 16,000, but have got a collision checking size of 500.

I need to convert 16,000 into a number with the same relative size but between 0 and 500, instead of 0 and 16,000.

For example, I would want 16,000 to equal 500, 8,000 to equal 250, 4000 to equal 125, 0 to equal 0, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just devide the number by 16000 then multiply it by 500 and round it the way you want it to.....